# Trying to read ID's from an XML file into different list?

Tags: java, xml, list

What I'm trying to do, is read the ID's of each Station,Track,Light,and switch, then create new instance of them, then add them to their respective list, then add all those components to the main list which is called Rails.
But it seem that in my method, when going through in does not event go into the body of the if,else statements.

Basically, I want to like read, there is a rail, lets loop through it, and if station make an station, add it to Station list, then to main list, then if track, create a track add it to track list, then to main list, and so on with the other objects.

XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<Rails>
    <Rail>  <!--Rail 1-->
        <Station> ST00 </Station>   <!--Station are type of track-->
        <Track> T01 </Track>
        <Track> T02 </Track>
        <Light> L01 </Light>
        <Track> T03 </Track>
        <Switch>S01 </Switch>
        <Track> T04 </Track>
        <Track> T05 </Track>
        <Light> L02 </Light>
        <Track> T06 </Track>
        <Station> ST01 </Station>
    </Rail>
    <!--Rail intermidate(here we will add the intermidate rail for the switch)-->
</Rails>
```

This is the arrayList and method(reading and store them), I'm trying to add them.

```
    public ArrayList<Object> rail = new ArrayList<>();
    public ArrayList<Track> stations = new ArrayList<>();  //Stations are type of track
    public ArrayList<Switch> setSwitches = new ArrayList<>();
    public ArrayList<Track> tracks = new ArrayList<>();
    public ArrayList<Light> lights = new ArrayList<>();


public void readXML(){
        String id;
        boolean doneLoading = false;


        try{
            File xmlFile = new File("/Users/luisgarcia-maldonado/Desktop/TDJ/cs351/smartRail/src/mapping.xml");
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbfactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbfactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = dBuilder.parse(xmlFile);

            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

            NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("Rails");


            Track station = null;
            Track trackOn = null;
            for(int i = 0; i < nList.getLength(); i++){
                Node nNode = nList.item(i);

                if(nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE){
                    Element element = (Element) nNode;
                    id = element.getElementsByTagName("Station").item(0).getTextContent();
                    if(element.getNodeName().equals("Station")){
                        //id = elemento.getElementsByTagName("Station").item(0).getTextContent();
                        station = new Track(id);
                        stations.add(station);
                        rail.add(stations);
                    }else if(element.getNodeName().equals("Track")){
                        //id = elemento.getElementsByTagName("Track").item(0).getTextContent();
                        trackOn = new Track(id);
                        tracks.add(trackOn);
                        rail.add(tracks);
                    }else if(element.getNodeName().equals("Light")){
                        //id = elemento.getElementsByTagName("Light").item(0).getTextContent();
                        Light luz = new Light(id);
                        lights.add(luz);
                        rail.add(lights);
                    }else if(element.getNodeName().equals("Switch")){
                        //id = elemento.getElementsByTagName("Switch").item(0).getTextContent();
                        Switch sw = new Switch(id,trackOn,null,null);
                        setSwitches.add(sw);
                        rail.add(setSwitches);
                    }

                }
            }
            doneLoading = true;

        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        linkComponents();

    }
```